# A decreasing transfinite sequence of subsets of a countable set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, borel-sets

Let $X$ be a **countable** set and $(S_\alpha)_{\alpha< \rho}$ is a decreasing transfinite sequence of subsets of $X$ in the sense that
$$
S_\alpha \supset S_\beta
$$
whenever $\alpha<\beta$. Here $\rho$ is some fixed ordinal.

> Suppose that $(S_\alpha)_{\alpha< \rho}$ is *strictly decreasing*, i.e. $S_\alpha \ne S_\beta$ whenever $\alpha<\beta$, how do we show that $\rho$ must be a countable ordinal?

I am sorry if this question is elementary, I have very little training in axiomatic set theory. I think I could prove by contradiction but some crucial steps are missing and I don't know how to make it rigorous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative proof: Since $X$ is countable, there is a strict well-order $\prec$ of $X$. For each $\alpha < \rho$ let
$$
x_\alpha := \min_{\prec} S_\alpha \setminus S_{\alpha + 1}.
$$
Now
$$
\pi \colon \rho \to X, \alpha \mapsto x_\alpha
$$
is an injection, witnessing that $\rho$ is countable (since $X$ is countable).

Comment: I don't understand why you're going to the $\omega_1$ route at all? You just get an injection from $\rho$ into a countable set. It's just confusing.

Comment: (And of course, the fact that the map is injective is *exactly* because these are pairwise disjoint sets...)

Comment: @Asaf Yeah, the part with $\omega_1$ was unnecessary. I've fixed it and blame inner model theory: Every proof in inner model theory is by contradiction ;-)

Comment: Okay, so now, how is this *alternative*? It's exactly the same proof as mine, only more explicit... :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I can't argue with that. All I know is that when I see you comparing sizes of partitions with sizes of the underlying set, an inner voice shouts at me that something very weird is about to happen. In this case, my inner voice urged me to point out (maybe to OP, maybe to myself) that your black magic doesn't apply here.

Comment: My magic is not black. My magic is just dark, evil, and moist.

Answer (score 3):

If it is strictly decreasing, then $A_\alpha=S_\alpha\setminus S_{\alpha+1}$ is non-empty, and $A_\alpha\cap A_\beta=\varnothing$ whenever $\alpha\neq\beta$.

How many pairwise disjoint subsets a countable set can have?